# Hide event post type if the date is in the past

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a website and have created a "Events" post type which is pulling in the events and showing them if they are greater than todays date:

```
<section class="row home-news bg-pale-blue" id="events__section">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="block">
    <div class="columns listing-title wide-gutter">
       <div class="col1-2 title">
         <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns article-listing news-listing wide-gutter">
    <?php 
      $today = date('Ymd');
      $homepageEvents = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type' => 'event', 
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => 'event_date', 
            'compare' => '>=', 
            'value' => $today, 
            'type' => 'numeric'
            )
             )
        ));
                    
        while($homepageEvents->have_posts()){
          $homepageEvents->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col1-3 item">
               <a class="blog-line" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
               <span class="date"><?php the_field('event_date',$post->ID); ?></span>
               <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
               <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_field('summary_text',$post->ID), 25); ?></p>
               <span class="more-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>&nbsp;Read more</span>
               </a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

What Id like do do is hide the entire section if there are no upcoming events, how could that be done?

Based on this I am only needing to hide the section if all current events are: 'value' < $today,

Many thanks

Comment: You can use `if($homepageEvents->have_posts())` where you need it

Comment: @ChrisHaas sorry I may have worded it wrong.  There's events but they are all in the past so not showing in the front end.  Based on this I am only needing to hide the section if all current events are: 'value' < $today,

Comment: just move your query outside the section, and use Chris' comment to check if your query has any results in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach to hide the section if all current events are in the past (i.e., 'value' < $today). Modify the `WP_Query` to return all events, not just those in the future. Then, you can loop through the events and check if all of them are in the past. If they are, you can return and not display the section.

Modified code in that part

```
<?php 
 $today = date('Ymd');
 $allEvents = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'event', 
  'meta_key' => 'event_date',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
  'order' => 'ASC', 
  ));

 $allInPast = true;
 while($allEvents->have_posts()){
  $allEvents->the_post();
  $event_date = get_field('event_date',$post->ID);
  if($event_date >= $today){
    $allInPast = false;
    break;
  }
 }

 if($allInPast){
  return;
 }

 $homepageEvents = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'post_type' => 'event', 
  'meta_key' => 'event_date',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
  'order' => 'ASC', 
  'meta_query' => array(
      array(
      'key' => 'event_date', 
      'compare' => '>=', 
      'value' => $today, 
      'type' => 'numeric'
      )
       )
  ));

 while($homepageEvents->have_posts()){
  $homepageEvents->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col1-3 item">
       <a class="blog-line" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
       <span class="date"><?php the_field('event_date',$post->ID); ?></span>
       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
       <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_field('summary_text',$post->ID), 25); ?></p>
       <span class="more-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>&nbsp;Read more</span>
       </a>
    </div>
 <?php } 
?>
```

The `$allInPast` variable here is used set to false and the loop is broken. If all events are in the past, the `$allInPast` remains true and the section is not displayed.